# Multiple network calls in the same time

Tags: android, android-viewpager, rx-java

I have this method it called from viewPager adapter because I set the offscreenPageLimit with the list size the issue is that this method is called N# in the same time, any way to control this method to be called nonparallel.

```
 fun getSubCategoryProducts(index: Int, mainId: Int, subId: Int, query: String) {
    storeProductsHasMap[index]?.let { liveData ->
        var page = 1
        liveData.value?.let {
            if (it.meta.current_page < it.meta.last_page)
                page = it.meta.current_page + 1
            else return
        }

        addToDisposable(productsRepo.getSubCategoriesProduct(mainId, subId, query, page)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ liveData.value = it }, { t ->
                    processError(t)
                }))
    }


}
```

My Pager Adapter

```
class StorePagerAdapter(fm: FragmentManager, var categoriesData: CategoriesData) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {

override fun getItem(position: Int) = StoreSubCategoryProductsFragment()
        .apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putInt("index", position)
                putInt("mainCategoryId", categoriesData.id)
                putInt("subCategoryId", categoriesData.sub_categories[position].id)
            }
        }

override fun getCount(): Int = categoriesData.sub_categories.size


override fun getPageTitle(position: Int) = categoriesData.sub_categories[position].title
```

}

Comment: Can u show me the full code of your adapter?

Comment: You already calling it enfinitelly  `addToDisposable(productsRepo.getSubCategoriesProduct(mainId, subId, query, page)`

Comment: @IbrahimAli because my server returns 429 when i did this operation.

Comment: @ArunAbimanyu i added it .

Comment: Based on your case if u want to change values based on position then that method will be called n times .we can use caching mechanism to reduce api calls or we change adapter from fragment state pager adapter to fragment pager adapter and setting offscreen limit to size to 5 or 6 based on your need